# Is Karafka compatible with applications other than Rails? i.e Sinatra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-kafka, rubygems, sinatra, karafka

I have a service that publishes a Kafka event whenever a user attribute is updated, now to consume and process this event I have a gem that uses Karafa. Every application that boots the gem will be able to process that event (if possible). Does Karafka work with applications other than rails? In my case, the service is written in Sinatra which publishes the event and the consumer is in the gem which is using Karafka.

Comment: It might work. What issues are you running into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of Karafka.

Karafka is a standalone framework and works with and without Rails:

Docs: https://karafka.io/docs/Integrating-with-Ruby-on-Rails-and-other-frameworks
Example apps (including a PORO app): https://github.com/karafka/example-apps